# Regex variable length

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that matches:

Length is between 1 and 10.

The 8th character can be alphanumeric [0-9a-zA-Z] and the rest have to be digits [0-9]

Valid

```
1
123
1234567890
1234567a
```

Invalid

```
1a
123456789a
12345678901
```

I have tried: `[0-9]{1,7}[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9]{0,1}` but that is failing miserably

Comment: Is `1234567a9` valid or not? And why you didn't included that sample into your question?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The length of `1234567a9` is 9 (between 1 and 10) and the `a` is at position 8. According the the description in the question it would be valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match either 1-7 digits, or match 7 digits, the 8th one being `[0-9a-zA-Z]` and optional 2 digits.

```
^(?:\d{7}[\da-zA-Z]\d{0,2}|\d{1,7})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d{7}[\da-zA-Z]\d{0,2}` Match 7 digits and one of `0-9a-zA-Z]` and 2 optional digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,7}` Match 1-7 digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4CRa5A/1)

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
^(?!.{11})\d(?:\d{6}[^\W_])?\d*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UQwoeI/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!.{11})` - Negative lookahead to prevent 11 chars;
- `\d` - A single digit;
- `(?:\d{6}[^\W_])?` - Optional non-capture group to match 6 more digits and any character in class `[A-Za-z0-9]`;
- `\d*` - 0+ (Greedy) digits;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could simplify The fourth birds solution by using `\w`

Like so:

```regex
^(?:\d{7}\w\d{0,2}|\d{1,7})$
```

But that’s basically the same.

Comment: Mind you, `\w` would match any word-character including underscore.